# Do i need to pass all the hidden fields as well with the form in scrapy

Tags: python, forms, httpwebrequest, scrapy

I want to know that if i need to perform some search on the job site , then do i need to pass only those variables which are visible on the form or all the variables , even some hidden fields like

The form is here  `http://www.example.com/search.php`

Now there are two fields on the form like   `searchTerm` and `area`  and there are 5 hidden fields

The form submits to  `http://www.example.com/submit.php`
Now i have these doubts

1. Do i need to open the form page with scrapy with form page url or with the post url
2. DO i need to pass the hidden variables as well or they will automatically gets posted with the form

Comment: I tried without hidden fields and it worked but i was not sure if that was correct or i am getting wrong results

Comment: What happens if you try the search in a browser? If you get the same results, then you can make the reasonable assumption that scrapy is being used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `FormRequest.from_response()` then all hidden values are already pre-populated automatically.

but in most of the cases you need to override them as well depends on website functionality and behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can go without some of the hidden fields, other times - not.

You cannot know the server logic. It's up to the website how it is handling each of the form fields.